# Angular 14 calling Child Component method from Parent Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I am getting an error when I try to call a childComponent method from the Parent

**Child TS.
**

```
   export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
     ChildMethod(){
       console.log('test');
     }
     constructor() { }
   }
```

**Parent Ts
**

```
   @ViewChild(ChildComponent , {static : false}) child!:ChildComponent ;
  
   CallChild(){
       this.child.ChildMethod();
     }
```

when I call CallChild I get this error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ChildMethod')
at GpmainComponent.CallChild (gpmain.component.ts:39:16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare your Child component in constructor.

in Parent.ts:

```
constructor(private child: ChildComponent) {}

CallChild() {
  this.child.ChildMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It could possibly depend on when you are calling `CallChild`.

> If you're calling it before the view has been rendered, then `this.child` will be `undefined`, thus causing the error.

*ignore the above, it was my previous (incorrect) answer*

---

Since you're initiating the child function call from a button click, have you tried using a template variable, and calling it directly in the `(click)` declaration of the parent's template?

```html
<my-child #ChildComp></my-child>

<button (click)="ChildComp.childFunc()" class="btn btn-link">
  Load Child
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. I tried in ngAfterViewInit with both true and false. 

I am calling the child after both components have been initialized from a button on the parent.

    <button (click)="CallChild()" class="btn btn-link">load Child</button> 
    
    CallChild(){
        this.child.ChildMethod();
      }

Comment: @ShervinShakibi please see the updated answer, this is an alternate approach that may help

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `static: false` and timing.

When set to false, the `ViewChild` query will be resolved after change detection runs and right before `ngAfterViewInit`. This means that if you attempt to call in in `ngOnInit` for example then `child` will be undefined.

You have 2 options:

- Try calling it later, after change detection runs and when it's initialized
- Set `static: true` if the child is not under an `*ngIf` and then it will be resolved sooner and available in `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. I tried in ngAfterViewInit with both true and false.

I am calling the child after both components have been initialized from a button on the parent.

```
<button (click)="CallChild()" class="btn btn-link">load Child</button> 

CallChild(){
    this.child.ChildMethod();
  }
```